# Как правильно проверить нет ли совпадений в базе

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задача проверить, нет ли совпадения в базе данных по нескольким столбцам.

делал так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM test WHERE uid = $uid or
  screen_name = $who or domain = $who and id_cabinet = '$id_c'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result_tracker) == 0) { // если нет то выполняем
...
}
```

Почему собственно спрашиваю: Заметил, что этот запрос не делает выборку по спадению с последним параметром. А это важно.

Как правильно проверить наличие совпадений?

Comment: Надо проверять по всем столбцам или только по нескольким? Т.е. если только uid совпадает - совпадения есть или нет? И возможно вы хотели такое условие: `WHERE (uid = ... OR screen_name = ... OR domain = ... ) AND id_cabinet = ...`? Или вместо `OR` хотели `AND` (если нужны совпадения по всем параметрам)?

Comment: В текущем варианте вы не только проверите существование, но и словите пару замечательных SQL-инъекций

Comment: Мне надо проверить нет ли в базе уже данных (пользователя vk) т.е. надо например перебрать все записи с id_cabinet = '4', проверять uid = $uid or screen_name = $who or domain = $who. если допустим хоть одно совпадение нашлось, то ничего не делаем, если же не нашлось, то записываем. Вот щас так поставил:   SELECT id FROM test WHERE (uid = $uid or screen_name = $who or domain = $who) and id_cabinet = '$id_c' не знаю правильно или нет. Но потестил записывает если нет записи и когда запись в базе находит, то уже не пишет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вам нужна группировка выражений в предикате?
Например

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM test WHERE (uid = $uid OR
  screen_name = $who OR domain = $who) AND id_cabinet = '$id_c'");

if (!mysql_num_rows($result_tracker)) { // если нет то выполняем
...
}
```

И еще у вас почему `id_cabinet = '$id_c'` сравнивается со строкой, у вас `id_cabinet` не число случаем?

### Дополнение

Если у вас `$id_c` все таки число, то нужно убрать кавычки – `id_cabinet = $id_c`

Comment: У меня в системе есть id кабинета, мне надо взять все записи по id кабинета и прошерстить по ним проверяя есть ли совпадения в полях uid = $uid OR  screen_name = $who OR domain = $who если хоть какой-то совпал, то ничего не делаем. мысль такая была. Понятно?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, да. Тогда попробуйте мой вариант из ответа (внес правки небольшие)

Comment: спасибо большое, я почти так же чуть-чуть ранее сделал. Но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Расставьте скобки в условии. Приоритет AND выше, чем OR. Поэтому когда выпишете без скобок

```
A or B and C
```

это равносильно вот такому выражению

```
A or (B and C)
```

То есть если условие A выполнилось, то С уже не влияет на результат, выражение считается истиной.
Если вас это НЕ устраивает, то расставьте скобки сами.

Answer (score 0):

Ну давайте посмотрим на ваш запрос

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM test WHERE uid = $uid or screen_name = $who or domain = $who and id_cabinet = '$id_c'");`

`"SELECT id FROM test WHERE uid = $uid or screen_name = $who or domain = $who and id_cabinet = '$id_c'"` вы не забыли, вы ищете одну строчку!

`"SELECT id FROM test WHERE uid = $uid or screen_name = $who or domain = $who and id_cabinet = '$id_c' Limit 1;"` С лимитом в разы быстрее выполнится и ваш скрипт не будет бегать по каждой строчке

`mysql_num_rows($result_tracker) == 0` Сомневаюсь, как помним в случае не удачи `mysql` возвращает пустую строчку), в случае удачи `SELECT` возвращает саму строчку), два запроса сократились) это 1.получение строчки, 2.сравнение есть ли сама строчка...

`if($result)` есть строчка `else` нету строчки
Сам запрос я разбирать не буду...

Да только щяс заметил `Заметил, что это запрос не делает выборку по спадению с последним параметром.` Можно сделать еще, сделать сортировку по id в обратную сторону, если нужно получить последнюю строчку, или я нече не понел что вы хотите)

Answer (score 0):

если вам надо проверить уникальность **комбинаций** значений в нескольких столбцах (одном и более), то можно воспользоваться таким, например, запросом:

```
select count(*) from таблица
group by набор_столбцов
having count(*) > 1
```

как видно из нижеприведённого примера, уникальностью обладает лишь комбинация из всех трёх столбцов (запрос не вернул ни одной записи):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84eda/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);

insert into t values
   (1, 1, 1)
  ,(1, 1, 2)
  ,(1, 2, 1)
  ,(2, 1, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select count(*)
from t
group by c1
having count(*) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84eda/1/0)**:

```
| count(*) |
|----------|
|        3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select count(*)
from t
group by c1, c2
having count(*) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84eda/1/1)**:

```
| count(*) |
|----------|
|        2 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select count(*)
from t
group by c1, c2, c3
having count(*) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84eda/1/2)**:

Answer (score -2):

в строке убывания алгоритма идет ошибка по ситаксису. Присмотри по проге может выявит.

И не понятна программа `mom_null` — мне кажется, она и жрет часть верстки, которая нужна в другой строке.

Comment: Я не смог понять это сообщение даже после собственной правки. :(

Comment: Я не смог понять даже перечитав